# Assistance with error message required

Tags: c

I have an assignment. I have the entire code but the snippet I am stuck on is the following.

The user must choose between the following projectiles. 
Each projectile has a blast radius and this is the code I have so far (for this section):

```
userProjectileChoice = myProjectiles[3]; 

myProjectiles[0].projectileName = "cannonBall"; 
myProjectiles[0].blastRadius = 10; 

myProjectiles[1].projectileName = "highExplosiveShell"; 
myProjectiles[1].blastRadius = 1; 

myProjectiles[2].projectileName = "mortarBomb"; 
myProjectiles[2].blastRadius = 1000;
```

I need to use the struct as it is required.
Error message is: `incompatible types when assigning to type int from type struct`

The following has been included so you can see what the above code is referring to.

Projectile name has not been declared, am I declaring it in the above coding?

```
struct Projectile
{
  char name[40];
  float blastRadius;
};

float blastRadius;
double cannonBall = 0;
double highExplosiveShell = 1;
double mortarBomb = 2;

struct Projectile myProjectiles[3] = {{"cannonBall",0},{"highExplosiveShell", 1},{"mortarBomb", 2}};
```

Any assistance would be appreciated, but please keep it simple for me to understand as I said before I am new to this.

Comment: Thanks heaps. I've managed to solve all other errors except for this one. Do you know anything about an error message that expects a statement or declaration at the end of the program? I have that for some unknown reason as well.

Comment: Without seeing the structure declaration, how do expect anyone to tell you what is wrong with it??

Comment: Message is clear: you tried to assign a struct to an int... Did you ever tried to use a leak as a screw driver?

Comment: That's not the question you asked, but you have perhaps missed a closing `}` brace or a closing `"` quote somewhere.

Comment: I don't see a _program_. Just a snippet of code completely out of context. Read [ask] and act accordingly.

Comment: Change this:
`struct Projectile myProjectiles[3] = {{"cannonBall",0},"highExplosiveShell", 1},{"mortarBomb", 2}};`
  To this:
`struct Projectile myProjectiles[3] = {{"cannonBall",0}, {"highExplosiveShell", 1},{"mortarBomb", 2}};`  In case you still can't see it, you are missing a squiggly bracket between `{"cannonBall", 0}` and `"highExplosiveShell, 1}`

Comment: Must've been a typo when I copied it in. I checked the program I have one. But thank you for the effort.

Comment: No problem.  What is the data type for `userProjectileChoice`?  Is it an `int` or `Projectile` or something else?

Comment: int userProjectileChoice = 0;

Comment: Okay, a couple things here.  1.)  you can't assign a struct to an int like `userProjectileChoice`.  The compiler won't know what to do.  2.)  You can't assign an index of an array that doesn't exist.  You have three separate projectile objects each with the respective index of 0, 1, 2.  Making any assignment to myProjectiles[3] should give you an error because it doesn't exist.  myProjectiles[2], myProjectiles[1], and myProjectiles[0] does exist.  Let me know if this is making sense.

Comment: Okay so I want to use the projectiles as choices with the respective blast radius. Can I assign an array to the struct with those names and radius'?

Comment: If i make the myProjectile a char can i assign the integer 3 into the [ ] so that there are 3 options to select? or am I thinking of another process?

Comment: How is the user selecting the choices?  Are there multiple selections being made or only one?  Could I select all three projectiles or can I select only one?

Comment: just one, by entering in either a 0, 1 or 2

Comment: I'll be back in about 3 and half hours, I desperately need sleep. Thanks for your help! I appreciate it.

Comment: so just collect the value of the entered number representing one of the projectile objects in the array (0, 1, or 2), place the value in an `int`, and use that `int` variable to reference the array to get the correct projectile object.

And no problem!  Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Dash. I managed to get it sorted.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what type `userProjectileChoice` is, so I'm going to assume that it is the same type of the `myProjectiles` array.  Try assigning each property one at a time as so:
`userProjectileChoice.projectName = myProjectiles[3].projectileName`
`userProjectileChoice.blastRadius= myProjectiles[3].blastRadius`

It's been years since I've programmed in C, but it's worth a shot.

Or perhaps you mean to assign the "index" and not the entire struct.  Like I said, it's difficult to come up with a correct answer when I don't know the type of `userProjectileChoice`.  Perhaps your problem is in the assignment at the beginning of the code.  So if the 4th choice is selected then it should be as so:
`userProjectileChoice = 3`